# java can't compare strings

Tags: java

i'm written a code that reads a line from the socket.

if the line is "bye" i want it to output "nice".
from some reason it doesn't work, although i did try to output the input with no conditions and it did says "bye"

this is my code

```
                String input = null;
                if (socket.getInputStream().available() > 0)                    
                    input = in.readLine();                                                                  

                if (input != null)
                {
                    input = input.trim();
                    if (input == "bye")
                        out.println("nice");

                    out.println(input);
                }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java String.equals versus ==](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`String#equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), not `==`, to compare strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (input != null)
                {
                    input = input.trim();
                    if (input.equals("bye"))
                        out.println("nice");

                    out.println(input);
                }
```

The `equals()`  compares the content of string.

Answer (score 0):

You want your inner if to say this:

```
if (input.equals("bye"))
```

instead of

```
if (input == "bye")
```

The `==` is actually comparing the reference object (sort of like a pointer) and may sometimes work when the string is interned, but that's another topic.  Use `.equals()`!